# Get each item in a collection with one query

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, model, mariadb

I have a collection of slugs and want to get each corresponding page with one query.

Something like ...

```php
Page::whereIn('slug', $slugs)->get();
```

... does only return the first page matching any slug in the collection.

Currently there is a loop, but that are dozens of queries I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `whereRaw` method and imploding your array into a string:

```
Page::whereRaw('slug IN ("' . $slugs->implode('","') . ')')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints to `whereRaw` and `IN`! I had to edit your solution, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, `whereIn` was the right way. There was one minor mistake in my logic, and at the same time insufficient seeding data, that blowed everything up.

If someone does not know: `whereRaw` should be used with caution. To avoid SQL injection vulnerability, all user-submitted entries have to be passed as parameters.

```php
Page::whereRaw('slug IN (?)', [$slug]);
```

Beware: Wrapping `?` with quotes is a syntax error. The passed data will be single-quoted by default, at least on my machine™.

```sql
select * from `pages` where `slug` in ('page');
```